# Single model from findAll()?

Tags: ember.js

I want to use my template & view to edit a single record. Server returns an array that may or may not be populated. Controller is ObjectController, and I currently populate it by findAll(1). How can I use findAll() and return first item in returned array or an empty object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is have an `ArrayController` to hold the results of the `findAll` call, and then bind to that as such:

```
App.RecordsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

App.RecordController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: 'records',
    contentBinding: 'controllers.records.firstObject'
});
```

In your route you can do:

```
setupController: function () {
    this.controllerFor('records').set('content', Blah.findAll());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Very clean and nice.